# PHP code is taking very much time in executing when handling large number

Tags: php, for-loop, execution, largenumber, prime-factoring

This is a simple program to find prime numbers which check for the division of a number at later stage.

I tried to short it by initially taking the integer square root of the number to break down the complexity. But still it is taking very much time in executing the script. What other changes I can implement in my code to decrease the execution time( I already set the max execution time to 5 min)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$num = 600851475143;
//$sqrt_num = (int)sqrt($num);

for( $j = 2; $j <= $num; $j++ )
{
    for( $k = 2; $k < $j; $k++ )
    {
        if( $j % $k == 0 )
        {
        break;
        }

    }
    if( $k == $j )
    {
        //echo "Prime Number : ", $j, "<br>";
        if( $num % $j == 0 )
        {
        echo "Prime number : ", $j, "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Just commented the line for sqrt as this seems to be in correct..but still the loop is taking much time.

Comment: How big can de numbers be? I will be shot by everyone with some sort of feeling for good code here, but if it is of limited size, it might be quicker just to cache the first couple of thousand primes rather then calculate them each time. And as they don't change, you really don't need to caclulate them the first time either, so instead of cache, read "hardcode".

Comment: @Nanne you mean I first put them all in an array and then apply division to the number ? Please clarify it a little more

Comment: @swapnesh division? no. I meant you put ALL primes in an array. Then you have an array of prime numbers you can echo jus as you are doing here. no need to do calculations. But it would help to know what the actual problem is that you need to fix?

Comment: @Nanne with this code my browser hangs ..however it is working fine when providing small numbers

Comment: @MarkoD why you thought so ? "though I know you didn't answer to me"

Comment: @MarkoD lol it is not such a case bro..actually I am too still looking in the code to make it working so may be i missed some action here..but really its not a case of ignorance :)

Comment: @MarkoD can you just post an answer..as I am out of mind this time lol

Comment: @MarkoD I just checked and placing sqrt is not going to be a correct method to use here ..I tested for $num = 1000 and $k <= sqrt($j)  and it was expected to come 2 & 5 but its only giving 2 in this case

Comment: instead of `for( $k = 2; $k < $j; $k++ )` write `$cond = sqrt($j); for( $k = 2; $k <= $cond; $k++ )` and instead of `if( $k == $j )` write `if( $k > $cond )`. And remove `if( $num % $j == 0 )` check. I tested, and it works. I will remove my previous comments as they are not needed now

Comment: @MarkoD Just paste it as an answer and I am desperate to accept it..thanks a lot bro :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to improve execution time of your code would be this:

```
$num = 1000;

for($j = 2; $j <= $num; $j++)
{
    $cond = sqrt($j);
    for($k = 2; $k <= $cond; $k++)
    {
        if($j % $k == 0)
        {
        break;
        }

    }
    if($k > $cond)
    {
        echo 'Prime number: ' . $j . '<br>';
    }
}
```

But there is no need to calculate prime numbers from the begining each time. You can remember every 30 seconds or so where you were, save the result to a database, file, or an array, and then restart the script, which should the continue from where it stopped.

Comment: To improve execution time even more: Handle 2 before the loop, then count from 3 by 2 in both loops.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to reduce this code execution time is by removing it. 
It's unnecessary to calculate every prime number each time you run this- they are not going to be changing any time soon.

Run it once, write it to a file or database and use that when you need it. 
I'd personally put it in an array for later use.

Comment: I put that it an array and still its running out of time for a smaller number ..check http://codepad.org/bJUjoom6

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic algorithm for factoring by trial division; I don't know PHP, so I'll just give pseudocode:

```
function factors(n)
    f, fs := 2, []
    while f * f <= n
        while n % f == 0
            append f to fs
            n := n / f
        f := f + 1
    if n > 1 append n to fs
    return fs
```

There are better ways than that to find the factors of a number, but even that simple method should be sufficient for the Project Euler problem you are trying to solve; you should have a soluion in less than a second. When you're ready for more programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend this [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog.

Comment: thx a lot for the pseudo code..it will really going to help me to understand more programming concept..and thanks for the link as well +1 for knowledge sharing :)